# Run the Jenkins pipeline nightly and after every commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We would like to run the Jenkins pipeline:

- nightly, but only if there was any commit in the chosen branches (dev or master)
- and after every commit

With the caveat that nightly build should also tigger additional step (long-running integration tests).

Is it possible? How can we configure this in Jenkinsfile?

Comment: "only if there was any commit" since when? After every commit to any branch? Should long-running tests run if there weren't any commits?

Comment: @MaratC Only if there was any commit from the previous nightly build. If there were no commits there is no need to trigger the long-running tests. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your question boils down to several:

1. How can I run a nightly build?
2. How can I stop a build if no commits were made in the last 24 hours?
3. How can I run a "long-running" stage, but not always?

Let's address these one by one.

1. You can have a nightly build by using `cron` or `parameterizedCron`, if you install the ParameterizedCron plugin. As you seem to want to run your job in all the branches, this may look like e.g.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        // schedule a nightly build at random time after 0am on dev branch, 1am on master
        cron(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'dev' ? '0 * * * *' : '') 
        cron(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ? '1 * * * *' : '')
```

2. To address the other points, you need to know why your build is running. It may be triggered by a person, or `cron`, or a commit. Once you make sure it's `cron` that triggered the build, you may want to explore `git log` for the time of the latest commit.

```
def currentBuildReason() {
    def timerCause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger.TimerTriggerCause)
    if (timerCause) { echo "Build reason: Build was started by timer"; return "TIMER" }
    timerCause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(org.jenkinsci.plugins.parameterizedscheduler.ParameterizedTimerTriggerCause)
    if (timerCause) { echo "Build reason: Build was started by parameterized timer"; return "TIMER" }
    def userCause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause)
    if (userCause) { echo "Build reason: Build was started by user"; return "USER" }
    println "here are the causes"
    echo "${currentBuild.buildCauses}"
    return "UNKNOWN"
}
```

and later:

```
if ( currentBuildReason() == "TIMER" and env.BRANCH == "master" ) {
   def gitLog = sh script: "git log", returnStdout: true
   // look for the date, and stop the build
```

3. Finally, you can run steps on condition. One way to do it is to define a parameter for your job, indicating whether the integration tests should run. This will allow a person to run them even if not nightly, when they select the box. E.g.

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'RUN_LONG_TEST', defaultValue: false,
            description: "Should long-running tests execute?")
    }
```

and later

```
        stage('Integration tests') {
            agent { node { label "integration_test_slave" }}
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                expression {params.RUN_LONG_TEST}
            }
            steps {
                // run integration test
            }
       }
```

To schedule the nightly with the param selected, you need the parameterizedCron plugin:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        // schedule a nightly build at random time after 0am on dev branch, 1am on master
        parameterizedCron(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'dev' ? '0 * * * *  % RUN_LONG_TEST=true' : '') 
        parameterizedCron(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ? '1 * * * *  % RUN_LONG_TEST=true'' : '')
```

Alternatively, you may disregard the parameter if only the nightlies should run it, and analyze the value of `currentBuildReason()`. When it equals to `TIMER`, these tests should run.